# Menu button not working. Will not display Menu page fragment

Tags: google-app-maker

I created a page fragment with a Menu button.  This page fragment is included on pages to add or view a document.

When the Menu button is clicked on, nothing happens.

In the page fragment, the Menu button has the below code:
    event.stopPropagation();
    toggleMenu();

The toggleMenu() function is defined in a client script library:

```
/**
 * Changes the appearance of the Menu widget on the page.
 */
function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = app.currentPage.descendants.Menu1;
  if (menu.styles.indexOf('hidden') < 0) {
    menu.styles = ['hidden'];
  } else {
    menu.styles = [];   
  }
}

/**
 * Forces closing of the Menu widget on the page.
 */
function closeMenu() {
  var menu = app.currentPage.descendants.Menu1;
  menu.styles = ['hidden'];
}
```

Comment: Couple of things to verify. Is your pagefragment on your page called Menu1? In preview mode does your cursor change to the hand cursor when hovering on the menu button or is it the pointer, which would indicate there is another element on top of the menu button? Just a couple of items I ran into before.

Comment: Check out most recent Starter App menu implementation it is way simpler than one you are trying to use: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/starter-app/